# parent zIndex problem IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, parent, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, z-index

For my understand. I need to put div 2 in front of div 3. How can I do this in IE6 and IE7. All of others browsers works normal. Here is my code.

---

CSS

```
    div {
        position:absolute;
    }
    #div1 {
        background:#0F9;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:500px;
        height:400px;
    }

    #div2 {
        background:#C00;
        top:20px;
        left:280px;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        z-index:3;
    }

    #div3 {
        background:#006;
        top:10px;
        left:10px;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
        z-index:2;
    }
```

Código

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>

<div id="div3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following in IE6/7/8, Chrome, and Firefox. This puts `#two` in between `#one` and `#three`

HTML :

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
       <div id="one">One</div>
       <div id="two">Two</div>
       <div id="three">Three</div>
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
 #one{
     background-color: #f1f1f1;
     position: absolute;
     left:105px;
     top:155px;
     z-index: 0;
 }
 #two{
     background-color: #c9c9c9;
     position: absolute;
     left:100px;
     top:145px;
     z-index: 1;
 }
 #three{
       background-color: #888888;
       color: #f1f1f1;
       position: absolute;
       left:95px;
       top:135px;
       z-index: 2;
 }
```

In Action: http://www.webdevout.net/test?02C

Comment: But in this way you changed the html and I can´t change. Do you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

See [Internet Explorer z-index bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug).

You need to explicitly set the `z-index` for your "`#div1`". Simply set `#div1 { z-index: 0; }` and your problem is solved.

http://www.webdevout.net/test?01c

Comment: This 2 answers do not help me. I need to put div 3 between div1 and div 2. And these answers. One put div1 in front of div3 and the other one duplicate the div and i can´t do that. Someone could help me?

Comment: If I explicitly #div to z-index:0 #div3 will be in front of #div2. This solution do not work.

Comment: Best solution, use flash! :-/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no known solution for this problem, since the #div1 gets automatically a "z-index:0" in IE7, which prevents the #div2 from overlapping #div3.

To make FF and Chrome behave more like IE7, add "z-index:0" to all elements with no "z-index" specified. This will not solve your problem, but might facilitate testing.

Comment: That's not entirely correct: in IE7 any element without an explicit zIndex is treated as 'natural progression' rendering so the implicit zIndex stack increases as you move down the page. Elements with an explicit 'position' property create a new stacking context (within the already applied implicit one) and therefore only affect their respective child elements. This is why z-index relationships in IE (upto 8) are inherently broken! It would also therefore be much more complex to replicate this behaviour in Webkit / Gecko engines than you imply!