# Bootstrap 3 buggy behaviour on IE8

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently published project in beta stage. Was testing it with new browsers for a while.

I fixed all bugs including background-size, some main css3 properties on IE8. 
The only issue on IE8 is following:

To recreate the situation please enter to the website http://goo.gl/rlmelu and click on, for example, birthday. Then enter number of participiants, ex, 30 and select some date. Then click "next".

That's how firefox 26.0 shows result:

http://joxi.ru/3w7gUv3JTJDfEIXmJqM

And thats how IE8:

http://joxi.ru/Eg_gUv3JTJB-EJupfnA

Please don't tell me to not to use IE8.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem: [Internet Explorer z-index bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156192/internet-explorer-z-index-bug).

I think it because IE8 has a weird behavior of z-index, i think you can work around the code by using `display` and `z-index`